# How can I keep on listen pub sub consumer in python flask app?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to listen pub/sub consumer on flask app the problem I am facing is the consumer is listening the messages only when the app is run but after that it doesn't listen any message.

Here's how I placed my consumer method in main

```
def consumer():
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")
    # Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
    with subscriber:
        try:
            streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
            streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer()
    app.run(debug=False, port=5000)
```

The output for above code is coming as

```
Listening for messages on projects/apnatime-fbc72/subscriptions/new-job-application-sub-event-local..

 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Is there any way I keep on listening till the server is up.